# Yield Return with Null

Tags: c#

Is there any way to optionally return a null with a "return yield" driven iterator?

I would like to return a null in some cases and I don't think this is particular to IEnumerable of type string. Same goes for IEnumerable of type int etc. Thanks

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var Items = GetItems();

    if (Items != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("<null>");
    }
}

static IEnumerable<string> GetItems()
{
    if (false)
    {
        yield return "Andy";
        yield return "Jennifer";
    }

    return null; // <- Compiler Error:
    // Cannot return a value from an iterator. 
    // Use the yield return statement to return a value,
    // or yield break to end the iteration.
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you need to things like that (or throw things like `ArgumentException` immediately), you need to separate your iterator into two methods:

```
 public IEnumerable<string> GetItems() {
     if (something) return null;
     return GetItemsInternal();
 }

 private IEnumerable<string> GetItemsInternal() {
     // the actual iterator with "yield return" goes here.
 }
```

Comment: the answer to what I asked for but mquander likely posted a more correct approach.

Answer (score 31):

You're not using an enumerable as it was intended (to iterate objects in a collection). If you want to keep your code similar to what it is now, you should do something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var Items = GetItems();

    foreach (var item in Items) //this will not enter the loop because there are no items in the Items collection
    {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    //if you still need to know if there were items, check the Count() extension method
    if(Items.Count() == 0)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("0 items returned");
    }


}

static IEnumerable<string> GetItems()
{
    if (false)
    {
        yield return "Andy";
        yield return "Jennifer";
    }

    yield break;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This just isn't encouraged.  When you're talking about a sequence, "null" should generally have the same semantics as "empty list."

Also, it's impossible to design the language to work in the way you'd like it to work here without extra syntax, since what if you were to hit a "`yield return [whatever]`" and then a "`return null`?"

Comment: I agree, it's a matter of intent. Simply falling through the function without hitting a 'yield return' will generate an empty sequence. Resposibilty for checking is the sequence empty belongs to something else.

Comment: Was not aware falling through generated an empty sequence.  Very useful info for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

While `yield break` is propably the best answer and it really does not matter since you always can do `Items.Count()` to check if greater zero or even do `for each on your empty result` there could be situations where it does matter if your result is an empty list or nothing at all and you still want to utilize the power of yield.

In that case this will help.

```
    private IEnumerable<T> YieldItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Action empty = null)
    {
        if (items == null)
        {
            if (empty != null) empty();
            yield break;
        }

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
```

Usage

```
        foreach (var item in YieldItems<string>(null, () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Empty");
        }))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to return a null `IEnumerable<T>` from within an iterator method.  You can return null values in the iterator but not a null `IEnumerable<T>`

What you could do though is have a wrapper method which either returns null or calls to the real iterator

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetItems() {
    if (false) {
        return GetItemsCore();
    }
    return null;
}

static IEnumerable<string> GetItemsCore() {
    yield return "Andy";
    yield return "Jennifer";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing that prevents you from doing a `yield return null;`, if it is appropriate (of course, the enumerated type must be nullable).

Comment: I'd be pissed if I was receiving null from what I thought was IEnumerable. Yes, you could make it a nullable string in the case, but why?

Comment: I didn't say that I recommend it, I just said that it's possible. And btw: A string IS a nullable datatype...

Comment: I think the big issue with this approach is that there is no consistancy. What if some elements are null and others have value? What does that indicate?