# MVC Model Binding: why can't I bind to an iterator property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iterator, ienumerable, model-binding

When my model has an `IEnumerable<T>` property that is implemented as an [iterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28VS.80%29.aspx) (i.e. `yield return`), MVC's `DefaultModelBinder` cannot bind to that property when incoming values use square bracket syntax (eg `"Foo[0]"`).

Example Model:

```
namespace ModelBinderTest
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    public class MyModel
    {
        private List<string> fooBacking = new List<string>();
        public IEnumerable<string> Foo
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (var o in fooBacking)
                {
                    yield return o; // <-- ITERATOR BREAKS MODEL BINDING
                }
            }
            set { fooBacking = new List<string>(value); }
        }

        private List<string> barBacking = new List<string>();
        public IEnumerable<string> Bar
        {
            get
            {
                // Returning any non-iterator IEnumerable works here. Eg:
                return new List<string>(barBacking);
            }
            set { barBacking = new List<string>(value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Failing example<sup>1</sup>:

```
namespace ModelBinderTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    [TestClass]
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public class DefaultModelBinderTestIterator
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void BindsIterator()
        {
            // Arrange
            var model = new MyModel();

            ModelBindingContext bindingContext = new ModelBindingContext()
            {
                FallbackToEmptyPrefix = true,
                ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders
                                  .Current
                                  .GetMetadataForType(null, model.GetType()),
                ModelName = "",
                ValueProvider = new NameValueCollectionValueProvider(
                    new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection()
                        {
                            { "Foo[0]", "foo" },
                            { "Bar[0]", "bar" },
                        },
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                )
            };

            DefaultModelBinder binder = new DefaultModelBinder();

            // Act
            MyModel updatedModel = (MyModel)binder.BindModel(
                                     new ControllerContext(), bindingContext);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(1, updatedModel.Bar.Count(),
                            "Bar property should have been updated");
            Assert.AreEqual("bar", updatedModel.Bar.ElementAtOrDefault(0),
                            "Bar's first element should have been set");

            Assert.AreEqual(1, updatedModel.Foo.Count(),
                            "Foo property should have been updated");
            Assert.AreEqual("foo", updatedModel.Foo.ElementAtOrDefault(0),
                            "Foo's first element should have been set");
        }

    }
}
```

The above unit test will update the `Bar` property of my model to be `["bar"]` no problem (with or without square brackets in the collection keys), but will fail to bind anything to the `Foo` property.

Does anyone know (at a low level) why implementing an `IEnumerable` property as an iterator would cause model binding to fail?

I'm not really interested in workarounds<sup>2</sup>, but rather some analysis, as I've exhausted my knowledge of the framework getting this far ;)

---

<sub>1: A unit test was the easiest way to isolate the problem for SO, rather than going through a whole MVC application example.</sub>

<sub>2: For example, I know that if I remove square brackets from the input and reuse the same `"Foo"` key for all the values, the model binding will work. However the real failing case requires square brackets as each item in the collection is a complex type with it's own sub-properties. Or another workaround: add a non-iterator `IEnumerable<T>` parameter to the action, and assign *that* to the property directly inside the action. Ugh.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple, really. The `DefaultModelBinder` won't overwrite your `IEnumerable<>` instance if it's non-null. If it's null, it will create a new `List<T>` and fill it.

If it's non-null, it has certain types of lists it knows how to deal with. If your list implements `ICollection<>`, then it will fill it. But your instance (with `yield`) can't be updated at all!

If you're comfortable with overwriting `foobacking` then you can work around this by writing a custom model binder.

Comment: You are right, implementing something like [`yield null`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765400/yield-return-with-null#1765422) proves to be another workaround, as it must trigger the model binder to assign a new list. Two questions though:
1) Why does removing square brackets from the input (ie passing `"Foo"` instead of `"Foo[0]"`) work?  2) `Bar` does not return null. Why is it successfully updated?

Comment: 2) Is easy. Your backing `List<string>` implements `ICollection`, so `DefaultModelBinder` can update it. Not sure about (1) -- model binding is quirky and it's probably unintentional.