# Syntax issue IEnumerable<T> method using yield return

Tags: c#, yield-return

Here is my method :

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetMonths(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    // if logs is not uptodate
    TimeSpan logsMissingTimespan = to - from;

    if (logsMissingTimespan != new TimeSpan(0))
    {
        return GetMonthsBetweenTwoDates(from, to);
    }

    return null; // Why this line ?
}

private static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetMonthsBetweenTwoDates(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{

    DateTime date = from;
    DateTime lastDate = DateTime.MaxValue;

    while (date < to)
    {
        if (lastDate.Month != date.Month)
        {
            lastDate = date;
            yield return lastDate;
        }
        date = date.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

it works fine but I think I can write something cleaner like this :

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetMonths(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    TimeSpan logsMissingTimespan = to - from;

    if (logsMissingTimespan == new TimeSpan(0))
    {
        yield break;
    }

    return GetMonthsBetweenTwoDates(from, to);
}
```

But I have an error message :

> Cannot return a value from an iterator. Use the yield return statement to return a value, or yield break to end the iteration.

Why should I have a `return null` and what is the correct syntax ?

**EDIT :**

So, the correct way is to use Enumerable.Empty :

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetMonths(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    // if logs is not uptodate
    TimeSpan logsMissingTimespan = to - from;

    if (logsMissingTimespan != new TimeSpan(0))
    {
        return GetMonthsBetweenTwoDates(from, to);
    }

    return Enumerable.Empty<DateTime>();
}
```

Comment: It would be better if it returned [Enumerable.Empty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042.aspx), because currently the calling code must distinguish between empty and non-empty results

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yield Return with Null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765400/yield-return-with-null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The forms of your first two examples produce different sorts of output.

Your first example returns an `IEnumerable<T>` directly if the condition is satisfied, and a null reference if it is not. Your second example *always* returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, but the condition determines whether or not it has any elements.

The second example is done by using an *iterator block*. The `yield` syntax is used by the C# compiler to turn the function that you wrote into a custom (hidden) type that implements `IEnumerable<T>` and a type that implements `IEnumerator<T>`. These types implement the necessary state machines in order to achieve (hopefully) the logic that you've placed into the function. Because of this, you cannot mix paradigms; you must either return an instance of `IEnumerable<T>` from the function (and not use `yield` anywhere at all), or everything must be returned via `yield`.

If all you're concerned with is the fact that you're returning a null reference, you could make the methods semantically the same by returning `Enumerable.Empty<DateTime>` rather than `null`.

Answer (score 7):

Because you have used the word `yield` it now expects the method to *yield* one element at a time. It must only use `yeild return` or `yield break` to return one element per iteration.

You should use `Enumerable.Empty<DateTime>();` instead of `yield break`.

Answer (score 3):

A method is either implemented with an iterator block or it's not - so either *everything* is in terms of `yield return` and `yield break`, or none of it is.

However, you don't *need* to do anything special. Your original `GetMonthsBetweenTwoDates` already works where `to == from`, because it'll never enter the while loop.

On the other hand, your use of `lastDate` looks suspicious to me - in particular, it looks like it'll do something different if `from` happens to be in the same month as `DateTime.MaxValue`.

Comment: The example is stupid, it's just for illustrate my purpose :-)

Comment: @Florian: Then I suggest you pick a better example in future :) Seriously, it helps if it's representative of what you're actually trying to do, as there may well be a better approach.

Comment: Ok, I take your notice for the future.

Comment: Even if I think I'll never use stackoverflow to ask questions because I'll receive a very good book[1] very soon :-)

[1]http://www.manning.com/skeet2/

Comment: @Florian: What Jon doesn't mention is that his books are just the output of a sophisticated AI that scrapes answers from SO ;)

Comment: @Adam... Really, really smart ^^ A routine that returns IEnumerable<SOQuestions> ? :D

Answer (score 0):

you don't need yield break to end the iteration at your first check.

```
if (logsMissingTimespan == new TimeSpan(0))
{
    return null;
}    
return GetMonthsBetweenTwoDates(from, to);
```