# Does IEnumerable from yielding can ever be null?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield-return

Does an `IEnumerable` obtained from a `yield` expression can ever be `null`?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765400/yield-return-with-null

Comment: this can be helpfull...http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/237034/Yield-Return-Could-Be-Better

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. The C# compiler converts your iterator block into an [iterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instance, which is what is returned from your method. This can never be `null`.

That said, it is of course possible to yield `null` values within your enumeration, provided that the generic type of your enumerable is a reference type or a nullable type.

Comment: What do you mean by "your iterator block"? You can get null values back, AND you can make `GetEnumerator()` return null, so I'm not sure what it is you're saying can't be null.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: A method body that contains a `yield return` or `yield break` statement is called an *iterator block* in the C# specification.

Comment: Ah ok I see what he means now. Still not sure if that's what the OP meant... probably it was though.